# Sprint Boot Servlet Registration on a different port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have a spring-boot application with a @RestController, and need to register a servlet on a different port, while the RestController is bound to the default port.

I have an application.yml file and a src>main>resources>application.properties file.

This is my Servlet registration class

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger (ServletConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MyServlet> servletRegistrationBean(final ServletContext servletContext){
        LOGGER.info("Inside ServletRegistrationBean");
        final ServletRegistrationBean <MyServlet> bean = new ServletRegistrationBean <> (new MyServlet (), true, "/endpoint");
        bean.setLoadOnStartup (1);
        return bean;
    }
```

Here is my MyServlet class:

public class MyServlet extends AbstractXServlet{
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger (MyServlet.class);

```
public MyServlet() {
    LOGGER.info("Inside MyServlet Constructor");
    settings().setMultipartEnabled(false);
    final ServletHandlerr servletHandlerr = new ServletHandlerr();
    
    //Http POST Only
    handlerRegistry().registerHandler(EHttpMethod.POST, servletHandlerr);
}
```

}

I want to define the port for the servlet on my application.properties file, different than the default port where all the RestController endpoints are. But right now, I can't get to print any of the log messages. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to define the port for the servlet on my application.properties file, different than the default port where all the RestController endpoints are

...which essentially means you want to have a separate web server, running on a different port than the rest of the application. Personally, I would create a completely separate `SpringBootApplication` for that purpose.

However, if you insist on bundling it together in a single app, you could [create an additional embedded container](https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet#3-programmatic-configuration-through-tomcatembeddedservletcontainerfactory) that does not register the default servlet (`.setRegisterDefaultServlet(false)`) and instead only registers your custom servlet.

You will need to make sure your custom factory does not override the usual auto-configuration of the embedded container that the rest of the app will be bound to. You might need to duplicate parts of the original `ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration` of the default servlet, and mark it `@Primary` to distinguish it from your custom servlet container.

Comment: Could you provide details please ?

Comment: Details of what, exactly?

Comment: I mean implementation details. Code base. Spring boot actuator does the same under the hood.

Comment: related question is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865611/how-to-register-servlet-on-a-different-port-in-spring-boot