# How to register servlet on a different port in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, metrics

In my casual spring boot application  I regiser servlet like this.

```
    import io.prometheus.client.exporter.*
    .....
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MetricsServlet> registerMetricsServlet(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new MetricsServlet(), "/metrics");
    }
```

This servlet is registred on the same port as application.
The issue is that my infrastructure(k8s and etc) is expecting that application and metrics endpoint works on a different ports(like actuator does).

How can I register third party servlet on a ddifferent port ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiple connectors and request filter. (All connectors are handle same way)

1. https://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html

pay attention to the lines from

```
   public FilterRegistrationBean javaMelodyRestrictingFilter(FilterRegistrationBean javaMelodyFilter) {...
```

2. [spring boot 2.0 listening on multiple ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554023/spring-boot-2-0-listening-on-multiple-ports?rq=1)

**Original answer here.** [Configure Spring Boot with two ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357135/configure-spring-boot-with-two-ports)